# Adobe Illustator bug in svg view, how to fix

Tags: svg, adobe, adobe-illustrator

[SVG share](https://svgshare.com/i/Uaj.svg)

It has no probmels with view in browser
[image]

But in Illustrator i have a bug:
white last charecters in every word

[image]

Of couse when i save this file, i get this bug in the result svg.
It happend with  2019, 2020, 2021 versions of Illustrator.
Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Where is the svg being generated from, and have you looked at the svg source code? It should help you understand why it is displaying white.

Comment: @TinMonkey,  i found that it happend becouse illustrator adding clipping-masks to my svg automaticly. Disabling it solve my problem